# Array de boolean para Integer

Tags: java, array, int, booleano, bit

Como posso transformar uma array de boolean, `boolean[] bits` no seu `Integer` correspondente?

Tenho uma função que faz exatamente o contrario, porém eu não a compreendi suficientemente para poder inverte-la.

```java
int input = 62;

boolean[] bits = new boolean[7];
for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
  bits[i] = (input & (1 << i)) != 0;
}

System.out.println(input + " = " + Arrays.toString(bits));
//saída: 62 = [false, true, true, true, true, true, false]
```

Como posso fazer para pegar esse array `bits` do exemplo e ter-lo como `Integer` retornando o valor `62` do `input` novamente?

Comment: Vacilei na resposta. Isso que dá não ler a pergunta direito.

Comment: Eu tava comentando :x ahaha, até editei a pergunta, posso ter me expressado mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo um outro for, tente desta forma:

```
int n = 0, l = bits.length;
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    n = (n << 1) + (bits[i] ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! exatamente isso, obrigado!